# Vim, how to map two tasks under one shortcut key?

Tags: vim, dictionary, keyboard-shortcuts, line, line-numbers

i like to have line numbers ON in Vim but sometimes line numbers are annoying. I have shortcuts set in .vimrc:

```
map <c-F12> :set nonumber<ENTER>
map <c-F11> :set number<ENTER>
```

for turning them off/on.

Is it possible to connect both tasks (turning off/on) under one key? I mean, when line numbers are ON shortcut should turn OFF them and turn ON when line numbers are OFF.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From Vim help, you can use the following syntax :

`:se[t] {option}!   or

:se[t] inv{option} Toggle option: Invert value. {not in Vi}`

See `:help set-option`

In your case, you could use:
`map <c-F11> :set number!<ENTER>`

Comment: Hey, it works thanks! I changed it to:  nmap <c-F12> :set number!<ENTER>

Comment: Nice, do you know how to display some message when I Toggle the {option} so I know whether the option is on or off

Answer (score 11):

In case you want also change between the relative line number, the line number, and no number you can use something like the following:

```
let g:relativenumber = 0
function! ToogleRelativeNumber()
  if g:relativenumber == 0
    let g:relativenumber = 1
    set norelativenumber
    set number
  elseif g:relativenumber == 1
    let g:relativenumber = 2
    set nonumber
    set relativenumber
  else
    let g:relativenumber = 0
    set nonumber
    set norelativenumber
  endif
endfunction

map <c-f11> :call ToogleRelativeNumber()<cr>
```

Comment: [From Super User :)](http://superuser.com/questions/339593/vim-toggle-number-with-relativenumber) `nmap <c-f11> :exec &nu==&rnu? "se nu!" : "se rnu!"<CR>`

Comment: Update: `'number'` and `'relativenumber'` have changed in Vim 7.3.1115. You can find an updated answer at http://superuser.com/a/604625.